# what is diffrence between android permissions and uses permission using in android services?

Tags: android

how to use android permission and usepermission for services?

I used android uses-permissins ,but i dont know how to use android permission in android development

Answer (score 1):

- `<uses-permission>` is when your application is seeking the user's permission to use some
- `<permission>` is when your application is requiring other apps to seek the user's permission to use some feature of yours.

Usefull links:

- [permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)
- [uses-permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    The "permission" tag declares a security permission that can be used to control access from other packages to specific components or features in your package (or other packages).   

    The "uses-permission" tag requests a "permission" that the containing package must be granted in order for it to operate correctly.
```